# Algolia optionalFilters acts like filters on virtual index

Tags: algolia

I have my index and virtual index, on my index query like:

```
{
 "facetFilters": [["objectID:12345", "tag:Luxury","tag:Makeup"]], // 12345 or luxury or makeup
 "optionalFilters": "objectID:12345" // put it as first
}
```

will return all documents that have given object id **or** tag luxury **or** tag makeup and puts object with id "12345" as **first**. It behaves like expected.

But when I run the same query on my virtual index it **only** returns document with given id "12456". So it behave like filter where in docs it says:

https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/managing-results/rules/merchandising-and-promoting/in-depth/optional-filters/

*Unlike filters, optional filters **don’t remove record**s from your search results when your query doesn’t match them. Instead, they divide your records into two sets: the results that match the optional filter, and the ones that don’t.*

Answer (score 0):

Weird. I just set this up and am seeing the same results. I don't see anything in the docs that would explain why the behavior would be different, so I'm reaching out to some engineering colleagues to see what's going on.

**UPDATE:**

Algolia virtual replicas and optionalFilters both do out-of-band sorting of results at query time. It looks like those two features are causing strangeness when they both try to do their sort. I've cut a ticket on this, but for now to get the results you'll want to use a standard replica with optionalFilters -- the standard replica will do index-time sorting and then the optionalFilters can layer their query time filtering on top of it.